# OpenUI5 table - bind multiple models to row items

Tags: uitableview, uiview, sapui5, models

I'm trying to have one table but with 2 models bind to it.
I need to do this: I have a table and 2 models assigned to the view. In the table deffinition I bind one model and items are shown correctly.

Now I need to bind 2nd model and have a logic like: show items from 1st model and add lines from 2nd model to the same table.
Is that even possible?

I tried this, but it's not wotking...The structures of the data in models are different...

```
<Table id="XXX"
            inset="false"
            items="{parts: ['model1>/ABC/items',
                            'model2>/XYZ/items']}"
```

for the item value I have this binding:

```
<ObjectIdentifier
                            title="{parts: ['value1',
                                            'value2'],
                                    formatter: 'sap.ui.aa.util.formatter.multipleSources'}"
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: s[T].push is not a function
```

Any idea how to connect 2 models with different Properties?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to bind more than one model to a control. But to achieve what you are trying to do, you can "append" new records from the second model to the first model.

Comment: This (appending data) is the last thing I wanted to do...as I wrote the data structures are different so it's a performance thing. But probably you're right that this will be the only option. Thanks for reply anyway. I'll keep this open for few more days.